# CoreFoundation functions in Mac OS X Assembly

Tags: macos, assembly

I have the following code in assembly (assembled by clang)

Updated to what I thought would cause alignment; still doesn't.

Updated again; code still seg faults even with your suggestions(thank you for the suggestions though Stephen Canon ) 
I also tried to subtract 4, 8, 12 all didn't work with same stack realignment issue updated with more info.

```
.globl _main
.data
_hw:    .asciz  "Hello World\n\0"

.text
_main:

push 8      # 4 bytes
push _hw    # 4 bytes
push 0      # 4 bytes
##https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringCreateWithCString
call _CFStringCreateWithCString # 4 bytes
## push CFSTR return value in eax
sub esp, 8  # 8 bytes
push eax    # 4 bytes
##https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFShow
call _CFShow # 4 bytes
add esp, 8 # remove padding from stack pointer
mov eax, 99
ret
```

**Program Execution**

Start of main stack is empty

```
=============== (0xFFFF)
|             |
|    STACK    |
|             |
===============
```

The I push 8, the address of _hw, and 0 then call _CFStringCreateWithCString. Now it looks like

```
=============== (0xFFFF)
|      8      |
|-------------- (0xFFFB) 4 bytes for 8
|  hw address |
|-------------- (0xFFF7) 4 bytes for address of hw
|      0      |
|-------------- (0xFFF3) 4 bytes for 0 (NULL)
|    call     |
--------------- (0xFFEF) 4 bytes for address to return to after call (eip?) Is this 8 on x64?
```

Then CFStringCreateWithCString is called saving the return address (popping it off from call correct?), popping the arguments off the stack and jumping to the saved eip address after executing and putting its return value in eax.

After that the stack looks like

```
===============  0xFFFF
|             |
|    STACK    |
|             |
===============
```

I then subtract 8 from esp so it now looks like

```
=============== (0xFFFF)
|   Padding   |
|   8 bytes   |
|-------------- (0xFFF7) (esp)
|             |
===============
```

I then push eax from CFStringCreateWithCString so the stack looks like

```
=============== (0xFFFF)
|   Padding   |
|   8 bytes   |
|-------------- (0xFFF7) # 8 bytes padding from subtracting the stack counter
|     eax     |
|-------------- (0xFFF3) # 4 bytes from eax, the return from last call, or is it 8 bytes on x64?
|    call     |
|-------------- (0xFFEF) # 4 bytes to return after call (eip?)
===============
```

After the call to CFShow (and it popping off its arguments and the address from call) the stack looks like this

```
=============== (0xFFFF)
|   Padding   |
|   8 bytes   |
|-------------- (0xFFF7) # 8 bytes padding from subtracting the stack counter, CFShow doesn't touch this as it only expects 4 byte address
```

I then add the 8 bytes to esp removing the padding so it looks like this

```
=============== (0xFFFF)
|             |
|    STACK    |
|             |
===============
```

Correct?

This is what I type to run the code, do I need to change something because the processor is 64 bit?

```
MacBookPro:HelloWorld user$ cat hand.s
.globl _main
.data
_hw:    .asciz  "Hello World\n\0"

.text
_main:

push 8      # 4 bytes
push _hw    # 4 bytes
push 0      # 4 bytes
call _CFStringCreateWithCString
## push CFSTR return value in eax
sub esp, 8  # 8 bytes
push eax    # 12 bytes
call _CFShow
mov eax, 99
ret
```

My compilation steps, using clang's built in assembler (gas I think) and then ld. This is on Mac OS X 64 bit Mountain Lion

```
MacBookPro:HelloWorld user$ clang -cc1as -filetype obj -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -o hand.o hand.s
```

Link it with CoreFoundation

```
MacBookPro:HelloWorld user$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o hand hand.o -lSystem -framework CoreFoundation
```

Run the executable.

```
MacBookPro:HelloWorld user$ ./hand
Segmentation fault: 11
MacBookPro:HelloWorld user$
```

results in the following error

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Add `-arch i386` to the clang command. You are trying to compile 32 bit code as 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this code and I am not familiar with this assembly syntax, but it seems wrong to me...

IMHO, the proper code should be:

```
.globl _main
.data
_hw:    .asciz  "Hello World\n\0"

.text
_main:     

    push  8    
    push  _hw  
    push  0    
    call  _CFStringCreateWithCString 

    add   esp, 12  ; remove arguments from the stack... 
    sub   esp, 8   ; align the stack for the next call...

    push  eax 
    call  _CFShow 
    add   esp, 12

    mov   eax, 99
    ret
```

Note, the add/sub sequence:

```
    add   esp, 12  ; remove arguments from the stack... 
    sub   esp, 8   ; align the stack for the next call...
```

I wrote it this way in order to clean the logic, but of course it can be reduced to:

```
    add   esp, 4
```

So, the final code:

```
.globl _main
.data
_hw:    .asciz  "Hello World\n\0"

.text
_main:     

    push  8    
    push  _hw  
    push  0    
    call  _CFStringCreateWithCString 

    add   esp, 4   ; clean the arguments and align the stack for the next call...

    push  eax 
    call  _CFShow 
    add   esp, 12

    mov   eax, 99
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function in which you crashed should be a dead giveaway:

```
misaligned_stack_error_entering_dyld_stub_binder( )
```

On OS X, the stack must have 16B alignment at the time of any function call[1].  This is enforced for calls across a dynamically-linked library boundary via a check function in the dyld stub binder, which is what caused your crash.  You'll need to add 12 bytes of padding to the stack before you `push eax` and make the call in order to satisfy this constraint.

Make sure to familiarize yourself with the calling conventions on any platform for which you intend to write assembly that interacts with C libraries.

[1] https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002492-SW4

---

Your modified example:

```
## push CFSTR return value in eax
push eax    # 4 bytes
add esp, 8  # 8 bytes
# call puts on last 4 bytes
call _CFShow
```

has a few flaws still.  First, the stack grows *down*, not up, so you need to subtract from `esp` to align it.  Second, you're trying to pass `eax` as an argument to `_CFShow`, so it needs to be at `esp` at the time of the `call` instruction.  Finally, you need to have 16-byte alignment before the `call`, not after it.

So instead, you want something like this:

```
## push CFSTR return value in eax
sub  esp, 12 # esp aligned 4 mod 16
push eax     # esp aligned 0 mod 16
call _CFShow
```

You can make it a bit cleaner by noting that `esp` already has 16-byte alignment at the point of return from `_CFStringCreateWithCString`, and you no longer need the `0` that you pushed onto the stack to call that function, so you can simply store `eax` in it's place and avoid further stack manipulation:

```
## push CFSTR return value in eax
mov [esp], eax
call _CFShow
```

Finally, don't forget to clean up the stack and restore `esp` to it's initial value before returning from your function!

Comment: Why is this not required for MASM? does Invoke handle it?

Comment: @Zimm3r: It's part of the OS X platform conventions.  Since MASM doesn't run on OS X, it doesn't have anything to do with MASM.

Comment: Ah ok, still annoying when coming to masm mac os x seems much more picky for seemingly very small performance improvements.